# Can't set background wallpaper in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, gnome3, wallpaper

I am using Debian Testing and Gnome Flashback (but it behaves the same in standard Gnome Shell).

It gives me plain white background, and I can't set my own. Also, the settings dialog for background looks funny:

[image]

Any ideas?

Edit: I have noticed I got background image back when I turned off "Nautilus controlling desktop". Of course, I no longer see desktop icons this way.

Update: I have installed Ubuntu (with Unity), keeping my /home partition. The same problem appears in Unity! I can't set desktop background.

Comment: What does `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` print?

Comment: `'file:///usr/share/images/desktop-base/joy-inksplat-wallpaper_1920x1080.svg'`, which seems ok. Look at my edit, the problem exists only when I want to have icons on the desktop. BTW, should this dialog really look like this?

Comment: The output seems indeed normal. The dialog, however, should not look like the image you posted. You said you get the same behavior in Gnome Shell, but does Gnome Shell actually work correctly: e.g. does moving your mouse to the upper left corner bring up the "Activities" window?

Comment: Yep, Gnome Shell works OK (if one's into that kind of stuff of course), and it shows the background image, unless I check "Have file manager handle the desktop" in the tweak tool.

Comment: Related: None of the methods in this U&L Q&A work? [How to refresh the desktop background in various desktop environments?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116541/how-to-refresh-the-desktop-background-in-various-desktop-environments/116806#116806)

Answer (score 7):

Managed to solve the problem, at least in Unity, but I guess it would work in Gnome 3 as well:

This setting was false:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons
false
```

So I changed it:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

And got my desktop background and icons instantly.

Comment: Perfect.  This worked for me as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, you can fix it by setting in Tweek_tool/Desktop file manager handler and icons visible - OFF

Comment: Can you add a bit more details to this A?

Comment: Sure. after some updates (I have Debian Testing and Gnome 3 too),  I notice that I don't have my background image on desktop (background became white, changing image didn't help), and I tried to find how to fix it  but the only way I found it's to remove icons from desktop, using tweak tool

Answer (score 0):

Some people are missing the point, **IF** you want your icons on the Desktop **AND** wallpaper. Gnome has decided you can not. It used to work, but now it doesn't.

Of course if you **DON'T** want icons, it doesn't matter, but if you **DO** want icons on your desktop **AND** wallpaper background it has been decided you can no longer have that.

This is one of the reasons Gnome has gone off track, lack of customization of things you might want, and imposition of things you don't want.

Comment: Do you have any reference about the fact this is a feature and not a bug?

Comment: Actually, it seems it is a bug in nautilus ([bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=726562))

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus stops rendering the background because `gnome-shell` starts drawing it. Debian and Ubuntu are applying a patch to reverse the changes in Nautilus.

See Debian bug report titled: [nautilus: White background when nautilus is managing the desktop](https://bugs.debian.org/726562).

*excerpt*

> With my machine up to date, nautilus is drawing a white background when
>   it's managing the desktop instead of the expected wallpaper. I can
>   reproduce this with a new empty profile.
>
> I'm not sure this is directly related to nautilus, this might be caused
>   by other libraries in the stack.