# How to refresh the desktop background in various desktop environments?

Tags: desktop, desktop-environment

In XFCE 4.10 I can refresh my desktop background with `xfdesktop --reload`.

I would like to know how I can do the same for as many as possible other desktop environments (Unity, KDE, LXDE, Mate, Cinnamon, GNOME2, GNOME3,...).

Comment: GNOME 3: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://${outputFile}`

Comment: Perhaps this is not possible with all desktop environments. On the [xplanetFX homepage](http://mein-neues-blog.de/xplanetfx/), I read: "Seamless wallpaper change in GNOME, KDE < 4.3, XFCE and XFCE4, Fluxbox and feh wallpaper changer (KDE > 4.3 with workaround)".

Comment: It seems that Unity and KDE do not require any command at all. Both desktop environments refresh the wallpaper automatically upon change of the wallpaper file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code example which detects the desktop the environment and reloads the dynamic wallpaper background explicitly when required by the detected desktop environment.

The code should work with GNOME 3, KDE 4, Unity and XFCE. Tested answers with solutions for other desktop environments are welcomed and will be up-voted.

```
if [ "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" = '' ]
then
  DESKTOPENV=$(echo "$XDG_DATA_DIRS" | sed 's/.*\(xfce\|kde\|gnome\).*/\1/')
else
  DESKTOPENV=$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
fi
DESKTOPENV=${DESKTOPENV,,}  # convert to lower case

case $DESKTOPENV in
  'gnome') {
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///tmp/wallpaper.png'  # GNOME 3 only
    };;
  'kde') {
    :
    };;
  'unity') {
    :
    };;
  'xfce') {
    xfdesktop --reload
    };;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the content of the root window (i.e. the background) independently of the window manager or desktop environment. The traditional utility [`xsetroot`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xsetroot.1.xhtml) only supports a solid color or a black-and-white image. Many image viewing programs can load a color image in popular bitmap formats to the root window, for example the [`xsetbg`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xsetbg) utility from [Xloadimage](http://www.freshports.org/x11/xloadimage/) or the `display` utility from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) or [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).

```
xsetbg /path/to/image.png
display -window root /path/to/image.png
gm display -window root /path/to/image.png
```

This doesn't affect your desktop environment's notion of the wallpaper, so it may decide to display its own content in place of yours from time to time.